# Give simpler examples of $L^p$ unbounded yet converging martingales

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

I read the following example in the book [Counterexamples in Probability and Real Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195070682)
by Gary L. Wise and Eric B. Hall:

[image: alma ata]

Does anyone know simpler examples? I do have one! I would be glad to present it unless somebody gives an example more interesting than mine. (So this is a question to be eventually self answered.)

Comment: I edited the title  because the previous one did not attract enough "customers."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this: Let $N$ be geometric with success probability $1/2$ (so $Pr[N=k]=1/2^k$ for $k \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$). Take $X_1 =0$. For $1 \leq n < N$, independently define:

$$ X_{n+1} = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
X_{n} + (|X_{n}|+8^{n+1}) &\mbox{ with prob $1/2$} \\
X_{n} - (|X_{n}|+8^{n+1})  & \mbox{ with prob $1/2$} 
\end{array}
\right. $$

For $n> N$ define $X_n = X_N$. Then $|X_n|\geq 8^n$ whenever $1<n \leq N$ and so for $n>1$ we have $E[|X_n|] \geq 8^nPr[n\leq N] = \frac{8^n}{2^{n-1}}\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest example I've found so far:

Let $f_1,f_2,...,f_n$ be random variables defined on $([0,1], \mathscr L,leb)$ such that

$f_n(x)=\begin {cases}
n^2, \ \ if \ \ x\epsilon[0,\frac{1}{n})\\
0, \ \ \ \ otherwise\\
\end {cases}$.

Then $\mathbb E[f_n|f_{n-1},f_{n-2} ...]=f_{n-1}$ and $\int_{0}^{1}f_n\ d\mathbb leb=n.$

Note that we don't really need $(\mathscr L,\mathbb {leb})$. However, explaining the simpler case would make the example more complicated.

$$EDITED:$$

My counter example is wrong. Here is the martingale I was having in mind:

$g_n(x)=\begin {cases}
n, \ \ if \ \ x\epsilon[0,\frac{1}{n})\\
0, \ \ \ \ otherwise\\
\end {cases}$.

In this case $\mathbb E[g_n|g_{n-1},g_{n-2} ...]=g_{n-1}$ is true. We did not have a martingale before.  However, unfortunately $\int_{0}^{1}g_n\ d\mathbb leb=1 $ now. That is, my example does not work as a substitute for the more complicated examples. I apologize. What is true in the case of the $g-$martingale is that $\int_{0}^{1}|f_n|^2\ d\mathbb leb=n$. But this has nothing to do with my claim. I goofed this whole thing.

Comment: Am I missing something obvious? Your "martingale" doesn't even satisfy $\mathbb{E}(f_n) = \mathbb{E}(f_{n-1})$. (Note that any non-negative martingale is bounded in $L^1$.)

Comment: @saz: You are right. Pls., see my apologetic edits above.

Comment: Interesting example of a martingale tho, with your $g_n(x)$, even if it is uniformly $L_1$ bounded. A simple "almost martingale" is $X_n=X$ for all $n\in\{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$, where $X$ is any random variable with infinite mean. Then $E[X_{n+1}|X_n, X_{n-1}, \ldots, X_1]=X_{n}$ trivially, but $E[|X_n|]=\infty$ for all $n$. Of course, I think martingales are required to satisfy $E[|X_n|]<\infty$ for all $n$.